# Regular expression not working in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using elastic search in my project and right now I am having a requirement to find out SQL insert query from documents.
To achieve that I have prepared one regular expression and have made the indexed field as keyword analyzer.
As elastic search having a few reserved characters I am escaping those but it is not working.

For Example:

```
(INSERT INTO\s+)('*\w+'*)(\s*\(['*\w+'*,?\s*]+\))(\s+VALUES\s+\(['*\w*\d*'*,?]+\))  expression should match following sql insert statement
INSERT INTO 'strea' ('g') VALUES ('1','2','2').
```

Below is my curl command

```
    curl -u kibana:kibana -XGET 'https://192.168.1.28:9200/fileindex1/file/_search?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "query": {
        "regexp":{
            "regex.content": "\(INSERT INTO\\s\+\)\('\*\\w\+'\*\)\(\\s\*\\(\['\*\\w\+'\*,\?\\s\*\]\+\\)\)\(\\s\+VALUES\\s\+\\(\['\*\\w\*\\d\*'\*,\?\]\+\\)\)"
        }
    }
}' -k
```